# How to Enabling Dark mode in Frames with single checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a webpage which looks like the figure below, I implemented a dark mode checkbox which uses a javascript file to switch between 2 different CSS. However, I have no idea how to implement the same when my page is divided into frames.

[image: My webpage looks like this]

Clicking dark mode only changes the colour of Frame1.

Here is the javascript function that I'm using

```
$('#mode').change(function(){   

    if ($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "darkstyle.css");
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "style.css");
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');

    }

});
```

Code for total webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frameset rows="10%,*">
  <frame src="adminFrame1.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
  <frameset cols="20%,*">
    <frame src="adminFrame2.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <frame src="adminFrameAdd.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
<head>
    <title>Admin Things</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

code for frame1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Team8 Library</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="pagestyle" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.deep_purple-purple.min.css" />
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color: #820077;">
<div class="topnav">    
    <a href="index.html">Logout</a>
    <!--<a href="#login">Login</a>  -->
    <label for="mode" id="cbox"><input id="mode" type="checkbox"> Dark Mode</label>
</div>
<h1 style="font-family: roboto; color: white; font-size: 3em; margin: auto; text-align: center;">Welcome Admin</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="changeCSS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

code for frame3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AdminAdd</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.purple-deep_purple.min.css" />
    <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: linear-gradient(to right, white, #e3a1fa); ">
    <div id="signup" style="width: 75%;margin: auto;box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px grey; display: block; margin-top: 15%; padding-bottom: 2em; background: #fff;">
        <form action="#">
              <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label" style="display: block;text-align: center; margin: auto;">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1" style="color: indigo;">Username <span style="color: red; font-size: 0.75em;">(Required)</span></label>
              </div>

              <div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent" style="display: block; margin: auto;">
              </div>

        </form>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="changeCSS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without additional code. Please share your HTML and CSS as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. For what it's worth, you likely have duplicate IDs or incorrect selectors.

Comment: Sure! Can you please specify if just HTML of frame1 or complete webpage?

Comment: #1 change to `localStorage.root`, #2 on checbox change trigger top parent and get all child frames document to force stylesheet change

Comment: It helps if we have a minimal example -- enough code to show the effect happening on frame 1 and not the other two... but no (or at least little) code that is irrelevant. Isolating the problem like this helps make solving it much faster :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Done.

Comment: @Arvind Thnaks! I kind of get the first part but I can't understand the second one, can you please elaborate?

Comment: By the way, `<frame>` is no longer supported in HTML5, you should avoid to use it. This is old syntax and design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the iframe document and set the styles the same way you do it in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');

    $('#mode').change(function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "darkstyle.css");

            iframes.forEach(function(iframe) {
                var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
                doc.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "darkstyle.css");
            })
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "style.css");

            iframes.forEach(function(iframe) {
                var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
                doc.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', "style.css");
            })
            localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');

        }

    });
</script>
```